# Rendering a non UIElement via binding

Tags: wpf, binding, uielement

If I have an object derived from `System.Windows.DispatcherObject` but defines a `ControlTemplate`.

```
public class A : System.Windows.DependencyObject
{
   public ControlTemplate ControlTemplate {get; set;}
}
```

which is a member of

```
public class B 
{
   public A NonUIElement {get; set;}
}
```

Is it possible to render this object via a Binding such as

```
<Border Name="Border">
<ContentPresenter Margin="5,0" Content="{Binding NonUIElement }"/>
</Border>
```

assuming the `DataContext` of border is set to an instance of B?

Comment: Yea, it should work, did you try this?

Answer (score 3):

The object will render, but not in the way I think you're hoping for.  `The Content` of the `ContentPresenter` is set to the instance of A.  WPF then tries to figure out how to render this instance of A.  It first asks, is this object a `UIElement`?  In this case, the answer is no.  So it next looks for a `DataTemplate` for the type.  In this case, there's no `DataTemplate` for the A class.  So it falls back on calling ToString().  So your `ContentPresenter` will display a `TextBlock` containing the text "YourNamespace.A".

The fact that A happens to have a member of type `ControlTemplate` does not affect this logic.  To WPF, that's just a chunk of data that A happens to be carrying around.  WPF only *uses* `ControlTemplate` when there is a Control involved and the `ControlTemplate` is assigned to the `Template` property.

So you need either to supply a `DataTemplate` for A (which of course can access the `ControlTemplate` and use it to render the instance), or create a named `DataTemplate` and apply that via `ContentPresenter.ContentTemplate`, or derive from `UIElement` instead.

Comment: Excellent explanation, thank you. However, when you say I need to supply a DataTemplate for A where do I assign this within my HierarchicalDataTemplate, which is what I am working with?

Comment: Probably the easiest way to do this initially is to assign it on the ContentPresenter.ContentTemplate property: `<ContentPresenter Content="{Binding NonUIElement}" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource MyNonUIElementTemplate}" />`.

Comment: If WPF uses will look for the ControlTemplate for NonUIElement before it tries to render it within the ContentPresenter specified in your suggestion, why do I still have to supply a DataTemplate?

Should this <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding NonUIElement}" /> not implicitley mean "Use ControlTemplate of NonUIElement to to render content?"

Comment: Also, what would the composition of MyNonUIElementTemplate look like?

Something like this simply throws a StackOverflow exception.

     <DataTemplate x:Key="AnyControlTemplate">
                <Border>
                    <ContentPresenter  />
                </Border>
            </DataTemplate>

I cannot seem to wrap my head around this.

Comment: WPF will *NOT* "look for the ControlTemplate for NonUIElement before it tries to render it."  As far as the content model is concerned, NonUIElement is just a chunk of data.  It does not know that you want the ControlTemplate property to have significance for rendering.  Per my answer, "WPF only uses ControlTemplate when there is a Control involved and the ControlTemplate is assigned to the Template property."  That is, the significance of ControlTemplate is implemented by the Control class, not by DependencyObject or the WPF rendering infrastructure.

Comment: I think that throws a StackOverflowException because you're essentially telling it to repeat the same rendering within a Border.  So it keeps trying to instantiating the template within the template within the template... until the stack overflows.  You need to do something like <DataTemplate><Button Template="{Binding ControlTemplate}" /></DataTemplate> (using whatever control has appropriate behaviour for what you want to render).  But looking at your answer, what you want is a DataTemplate, not a ControlTemplate.  I'll post a comment to that answer.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it with this;

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:MapLayerModel}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Children, Mode=OneTime}">   
**<ContentControl Margin="5" Content="{Binding LayerRepresentation}" Template="{Binding LayerRepresentation.ControlTemplate}" Mode=OneTime/>**
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

This has been a great personal lesson on WPF templating and its content control model.  Thanks again itowlson.